# 3d rotation about arbitrary axis from 3D math primer for graphics

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

[image]

The steps are for rotating the vetor v around the vector n by an angle theta so that v lands at v', can someone please elaborate how he got the perpendicular component for v', thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we were doing a rotation in 2d you have a rotation matrix

```
R = ( cos theta       -sin theta )
    ( sin theta        cos theta )
```

And the rotation of a vector **v** is R **v**. Using **i**, **j** for our two basis vectors the result of rotating *x* **i** + *y* **j** is

(*x* cos theta - *y* sin theta) **i** + (*x* sin theta  + *y* sin theta) **j**

in particular the rotation of a vector along the **i** axis *x* **i** is

(*x* cos theta) **i** + (*x* sin theta) **j**

Now in the 3D case you can consider this as basically a rotation in the plane spanned by **v**_perp and **w**. Let **i** be a unit length vector in the **v**_perp direction and **j** be a unit length vector in the **w** direction. Let *x* be the length of **v**_perp, so **v**_perp = *x* **i**. The rotation of this is

(*x* cos theta) **i** + (*x* sin theta) **j**
= cos theta **v**_perp + sin theta **w**

As **w** has been set to be a vector of length *x*. This is the formula given.